# Why doesn't std::ranges::upper_bound accept heterogenous comparing?

Tags: c++, c++20, projection, c++-concepts, std-ranges

This code works and returns an iterator to `foo{5}` from the vector:

```
struct foo {
    int value;
};

auto main() -> int {
    auto ints = std::vector<foo>{{3}, {2}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {0}, {4}, {6}};

    std::ranges::sort(ints, {}, &foo::value);
    auto it = std::upper_bound(
            ints.begin(), ints.end(),
            4,
            [](const int v, const foo f) {
                return v < f.value;
            }
    );
}
```

This, however, doesn't compile:

```
struct foo {
    int value;
};

auto main() -> int {
    auto ints = std::vector<foo>{{3}, {2}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {0}, {4}, {6}};

    std::ranges::sort(ints, {}, &foo::value);
    auto it = std::ranges::upper_bound(     // the only change - added ::ranges
            ints,
            4,
            [](const int v, const foo f) {
                return v < f.value;
            }
    );
    std::cout << it->value;
}
```

Is the alteration of the behavior intentional or accidental?

The error message boils down to not satisfying the following constraint:

> ```
> note: the expression 'is_invocable_v<_Fn, _Args ...> [with _Fn = main::._anon_76&; _Args = {int&, int&}]' evaluated to 'false'
> ```

Well, yeah, you can't call that with two `int&`s. I suspect it may be intentional since the "standard" way would be to use the projection like so:

```
struct foo {
    int value;
};

auto main() -> int {
    auto ints = std::vector<foo>{{3}, {2}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {0}, {4}, {6}};

    std::ranges::sort(ints, {}, &foo::value);
    auto it = std::ranges::upper_bound(ints, 4, {}, &foo::value); // using projection
    std::cout << it->value;
}
```

Is this the rationale? Looking at the fairly complilated signature of template parameters of [`std::ranges::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/upper_bound) didn't really shine any light on it for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I suspect it may be intentional since the "standard" way would be to use the projection like so:

This is basically *the* motivation for projections. From [N4128](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html#algorithms-should-take-invokable-projections):

> The Adobe Source Libraries (ASL)[1] pioneered the use of “projections” to make the algorithms more powerful and expressive by increasing interface symmetry. Sean Parent gives a motivating example in his “C++ Seasoning” talk[15], on slide 38. With today’s STL, when using sort and lower_bound together with user-defined predicates, the predicate must sometimes differ. Consider:
>
> ```cpp
> std::sort(a, [](const employee& x, const employee& y)
>              { return x.last < y.last; });
> auto p = std::lower_bound(a, "Parent", [](const employee& x, const string& y)
>                                        { return x.last < y; });
> ```
>
> Notice the different predicates used in the invocations of sort and lower_bound. Since the predicates are different, there is a chance they might get out of sync leading to subtle bugs.
>
> By introducing the use of projections, this code is simplified to:
>
> ```cpp
> std::sort(a, std::less<>(), &employee::last);
> auto p = std::lower_bound(a, "Parent", std::less<>(), &employee::last);
> ```
>
> Every element in the input sequence is first passed through the projection `&employee::last`. As a result, the simple comparison predicate `std::less<>` can be used in both places.

Whereas `std::sort` takes a homogeneous comparison and `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` each take a heterogeneous comparison (with the arguments in opposite order), the `std::ranges::` versions of these algorithms all take homogeneous comparisons. `std::ranges::lower_bound` and `std::ranges::upper_bound` achieve heterogeneity with the projection, which is simply internally applied to the range's element before passing it into the homogeneous comparison, while `std::ranges::sort` applies the projection to both arguments.

This is a lot easier to use, less code to write, and less error prone: because you just have the one comparison that you use for all three algorithms, and you don't have to remember the order of arguments for the two `bound` algorithms.

Answer (score 6):

> Is the alteration of the behavior intentional or accidental?

This is intentional.

The function signature of [`ranges::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/upper_bound) is as follows:

```
template<std::forward_iterator I, std::sentinel_for<I> S,
         class T, class Proj = std::identity,
         std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
           const T*,
           std::projected<I, Proj>> Comp = ranges::less>
constexpr I 
upper_bound(I first, S last, const T& value, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {});
```

When you call:

```
auto it = std::ranges::upper_bound(ints, 4, 
  [](const int v, const foo f) { return v < f.value; });
```

The compiler needs to check whether [`indirect_strict_weak_order`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirect_strict_weak_order) is satisfied. In your example, `T` is `int`, `Comp` is the type of lambda, and `I` is `vector<foo>::iterator`, and since you did not specify `Proj`, the constraint can be simplified as

```
static_assert(
  std::indirect_strict_weak_order<Comp, const int*, std::vector<foo>::iterator>);
```

And `indirect_strict_weak_order` is defined as follows

```
template< class F, class I1, class I2 = I1 >
concept indirect_strict_weak_order =
  std::indirectly_readable<I1> &&
  std::indirectly_readable<I2> &&
  std::copy_constructible<F> &&
  std::strict_weak_order<F&, std::iter_value_t<I1>&, std::iter_value_t<I2>&> && 
  //...
```

Among them, `std::strict_weak_order<...>` is replaced with

```
static_assert(
  std::strict_weak_order<Comp&, 
    std::iter_value_t<const int*>&, 
    std::iter_value_t<std::vector<foo>::iterator>&>);
```

That is

```
static_assert(std::strict_weak_order<Comp&, int&, foo&>);
```

And [`strict_weak_order`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/relation) is defined as follows

```
template<class R, class T, class U>
concept strict_weak_order = std::relation<R, T, U>;
```

which requires [`std::relation<R, T, U>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/relation) which requires:

```
template<class R, class T, class U>
concept relation =
  std::predicate<R, T, T> && std::predicate<R, U, U> &&
  std::predicate<R, T, U> && std::predicate<R, U, T>;
```

In the above constraints, it requires `std::predicate<R, T, T>` to be satisfied, where `R` is `Comp&` which is an lvalue lambda type, and `T` is `int&`, since your lambda cannot invoke with `{int&, int&}`, so the constraints are not satisfied.

---

> I suspect it may be intentional since the "standard" way would be to
> use the projection like so:

Yes, this is recommended.

Quoting from the [N4128 13.2 Algorithms Should Take Invokable Projections](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html#algorithms-should-take-invokable-projections):

> With today’s STL, when using `sort` and `lower_bound` together with
> user-defined predicates, the predicate must sometimes differ.
> Consider:
>
> ```
> std::sort(a, [](const employee& x, const employee& y)
>              { return x.last < y.last; }); 
> auto p = std::lower_bound(a, "Parent", [](const employee& x, const string& y) 
>                                        { return x.last < y; });
> ```
>
> Notice the different predicates used in the invocations of `sort` and
> `lower_bound`. Since the predicates are different, there is a chance
> they might get out of sync leading to subtle bugs.
>
> By introducing the use of projections, this code is simplified to:
>
> ```
>  std::sort(a, std::less<>(), &employee::last); 
>  auto p = std::lower_bound(a, "Parent", std::less<>(), &employee::last);
> ```
>
> Every element in the input sequence is first passed through the projection
> `&employee::last`. As a result, the simple comparison predicate
> `std::less<>` can be used in both places.

Comment: That's one part of my question answered (or rather, a subpart) on what's exactly speified in the concepts. Upvoted, but I'd like to hear the rationale behind it, preferably supported by paper or discussion citation.

Comment: @Fureeish. I am not the person who designed the concept of ranges algorithm. For its design philosophy, you can refer to the original ranges papers like [P0896](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0896r4.pdf) and some early documents of [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).