# How to make ranges::binary_search (heterogeneous search in particualar) work with references

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I am trying to make reference wrappers work with heterogeneous search, and make it ranges-compliant. Here is the snippet I want to work:

```cpp
struct addressable { int address; };

template <typename T>
struct ref : std::reference_wrapper<T> {
    // comparisons for heterogeneous search
}

template <typename T>
ref<T> wrap_ref(T& value) { return {value}; }

int main() {
    const std::vector<addressable> nums { {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6} };
    ref_vec<const addressable> num_refs;
    for (const auto& num : nums) { num_refs.push_back(wrap_ref(num)); }
    const auto found = std::ranges::binary_search(num_refs, 2); // doesn't work
}
```

The heterogeneous search is working fine for classic `std` algorithms (for them it is enough to implement `<` and `==`. Now, `ranges` ones have more stringent requirements, so I tried implementing strong ordering operations in the following manner:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct ref : std::reference_wrapper<T> {
    auto operator<=>(const ref<T>& other) const {
        return std::reference_wrapper<T>::get().address <=> other.get().address;
    }
    
    bool operator==(const ref<T>& other) const {
        return std::reference_wrapper<T>::get().address == other.get().address;
    }

    // heterogeneous comparisons
    friend auto operator<=>(const ref<T>& l, const int r) { return l.get().address <=> r; }
    friend auto operator<=>(const int l, const ref<T>& r) { return l <=> r.get().address; }
    friend bool operator==(const ref<T>& l, const int r) { return l.get().address == r; }
    friend bool operator==(const int l, const ref<T>& r) { return l == r.get().address; }
};
```

This, however, leads to a number of compilation errors, which seem to warn about `indirect_strict_weak_order` and `strict_weak_order` concepts not being resolved. I do not understand why aren't they resolved - we have strong order, and references are, to my understanding, properly supported for the indirect part. What am I missing?

Here is compiler explorer example: https://godbolt.org/z/8xaWfah9b.

Comment: Don't you get misc. other errors before even reaching the line you've marked out?

Comment: @TedLyngmo well, there is only one error: `error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const __binary_search_fn'` and then the list of three candidate templates ignored: two due to the mentioned concepts and one due to different number of operands.

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't compile for a number of reasons unrelated to your question.  In consequence, I didn't look at the second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ranges algorithms don't work with heterogenous comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70365877). Use a projection:

```cpp
std::ranges::binary_search(num_refs, 2, {}, [](ref<const addressable> r) {
    return r.get().address;
});
```

In this specific case, you can't use `ranges::less{}(2, ref<const addressable>(...))`, because [`ranges::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ranges/less) requires the two arguments to be [`totally_ordered`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/totally_ordered) with each other, which requires them to have a [`common_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_reference). There is no common reference between `const int&` and `const ref<const addressable>&`, unless you add a conversion from `ref<const addressable>` to `const int&`.

Comment: Right! Projections went completely over my head, this makes sense from the design standpoint, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> The heterogeneous search is working fine for classic `std` algorithms
> (for them it is enough to implement `<` and `==`. Now, `ranges` ones have
> more stringent requirements

The `ranges` version uses `ranges::less` for comparison by default, which has stricter syntactic and semantic requirements for comparison types than the `std` version, but you can still pass `std::less` as a comparator that only requires expressions `lhs < rhs` to be valid

```
const auto found = ra::binary_search(num_refs, 2, std::less{});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gq4KEEs3f)